# How to double join the sql query?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have build this sql query and it works fine on phpmyadmin and as well as codeigniter;

```
SELECT teams.team_name,
COUNT(matches.winner) AS win
FROM matches
RIGHT JOIN teams ON teams.team_name = matches.winner
GROUP BY teams.team_name, matches.winner
ORDER BY win DESC
```

OUTPUT:

```
| team_name    |  win    |
------------------------------
|    India     |    1    |
|    Australia |    4    |
|    England   |    1    |
| South Africa |    0    |
```

But i need the below output: (There is another column "loser") Hence i need to apply the same query for the "loser" column similar to that i have done with "win" column.

Expected Output :

```
| team_name    |  win    | loss
------------------------------
|    India     |    1    |  2
|    Australia |    4    |  3
|    England   |    1    |  1
| South Africa |    0    |  2
```

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results will help, please have a read of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

One method would be correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t.team_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM matches m
        WHERE t.team_name = m.winner
       ) as num_wins,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM matches m
        WHERE t.team_name = m.loser
       ) as num_loses
FROM matches t
ORDER BY num_wins DESC;
```